# Exception handling or just sys.exit in python

Tags: python, exception

Im validating dates based on user input and cant figure out how to validate date greater than today's date

```
def validate(date_text):
       if datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d') > datetime.datetime.now():
           print "Enter date greater than today's date"
           sys.exit()
```

Is this the way to do it or can we do exception handling ?

Comment: After seeing that tiny slice of what is indubitably a larger program, I can without a shred of doubt say that the answer to your question is... maybe.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe? If you want to quit your program then do it. If you want to raise an exception instead, you can just do it too:

```
def validate(date_text):
   if datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d') > datetime.datetime.now():
       raise ValueError(Enter date greater than today's date")
```

It's possible that you have more similar exceptions like this. If you want to distinguish it, you should make new exception classes:

```
class DateTooGreatError(BaseException):
    pass
```

And to use your new exception:

```
def validate(date_text):
   if datetime.datetime.strptime(date_text, '%Y-%m-%d') > datetime.datetime.now():
       raise DateTooGreatError(Enter date greater than today's date")
```

Then, you can just handle it normally:

```
try:
    validate(date_text)
except DateTooGreatError:
    ...
except DateIsStillTwentyYearsToGoError:
    ...
except:
    ...
```

Comment: i have another exception to raise if the date format is incorrect. Can i be able to handle both the exceptions which are of the type ValueError at the same time ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response. That helped me. Turned out i have to quit the program if the dates are not validated. So i have to go with sys.exit

Comment: @alKid : Sorry for asking it a little late. Is it better to catch the exception and exit from it , or just print a message and exit as did in the question ?

Comment: That's up to you.. I think the latter is better. Why do you want to catch an exception if you don't want to do anything about it?

Comment: @alKid : i have a lot of conditions to check , if it is exception handling then i can just print the error message thrown by the exception and exit , else i have to write down the print messages for each condtion with if statements and then exit. But i dont know which one is efficient